# Javascript: retrieve array index of object by getting the modulo of minutes with the length of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my javascript program I have created object and 5 instances. I have created array. After that I am getting current minutes by date object and array length. Now I want to do following: 
1). Determine the index to retrieve the object by getting the modulo of minutes with the length of the array.
2). Display the link to the URL.
3). Set the timer to run every minute that means We should be able to see a different link every minute.

To determine index I calculated length of array and modulo of minute. So still I am confused retrieving object by getting the modulo of minutes with the length of the array.

I have also set time interval which should change link every minutes. but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me ?

code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    div p {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    a{
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3bb570;

    }   

    a:hover{
        color:#efa5db
    }

</style>
<title>lab15</title>

</head>
<body background="lab15_images/pink.jpg">
    <div class="myDiv" id="div">
        <p> Click on the link to see a website. </p>
        <!-- <p><b><a href="#" id="link">  </a></b></p> -->
        <p id="link">  </p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function web(url, name) {
            this.url = url;
            this.name = name;
        }

        var myWeb = new site("http://www.cnn.com/", "CNN");
        var myWeb2 = new site("http://www.bbc.com/news", "BBC");

        var array = new Array(myWeb, myWeb2);


        setInterval(changeLink, 60000);

        function changeLink() {

            var n = new Date().getMinutes();
            var site = instances[index] 
            var counter = 0;

            var ele = document.getElementbyId("link");
            ele.innerHTML = instances[counter];
            counter++;

            if(counter >= instances.length) {
                counter = 0;
            }

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var myDiv = document.getElementbyId("div");
            a.href = site.the_url;
            myDiv.appendChild(a);
            document.body.appendChild(myDiv);

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To make things come up  you need to  replace  document.getElementbyID("div")  With
var myDiv = document.getElementById("div");
and add inner text to your anchor tag .
example -: a.innerText ="myWebsite.website_name"

Answer (score 2):

The modulus of a number `m` `m % n` will never be larger than `n - 1`. So you have minutes from 0 - 60 and you want to convert that into array index 0 - 4, you just need `minutes % array.length`. In other words to get a particular site given a minute you only need:

```
 var n = new Date().getMinutes();
 var index = n % instances.length
 var site = instances[index]
```

You actually don't need `var mod = n % 60;` because `d.getMinutes()` will always return a number between 0 and 59 already.

I would put those calculations inside your `changeLink()` function:

```
function changeLink() {
    var n = new Date().getMinutes();
    var index = n % instances.length
    var site = instances[index] 

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("div");
    myDiv.appendChild(a);
    a.title = site.website_name;
    a.href = site.the_url;
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
}
```

This leaves you with another problem: what happens when you have displayed all your sites? Do you just keep repeating and append the same sites? Do you stop?

Comment: I pasted your code but link is not under div tag...still it's blank..can you please suggest further ?

Comment: Two things: there's an error in your javascript: `getElementById` not `getElementbyID`. Also you need to add some text to your anchors if you want to see them. Maybe something like: `a.innerHTML = site.website_name`. Also to get examples like you posted in the images, you will need to do more than just add a link. You'll probably want to add a whole new div.

Comment: I want to Put link inside same div I created.

Comment: I updated code I have put counter which should run up to array length but still it doesn't work. can you please suggest further ?